# How to update data without page refresh using react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to update data in a table on saving data without page refresh using react and typescript.

what i am trying to do?

I have a table with some data and edit icon.

on clicking edit icon it opens another view where we can edit the data that was available in table. This view has also save button.

On editing data in table and clicking save button it takes me back to view of the table with data. In here i expect to see previous table data to be replaced with new saved data.

But for some reason the table data doesnt get updated.

below is my code,

```
const Details = ({
    match: {params: {id},},
}: RouteComponentProps<{id: string}>) => {
    const { loading, data, error, refetch } = useDetailsQuery({
        variables,
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    }); //data is here is not updated on saving the data.

    const details = data?.details
                        ? data.details
                        : {};
    const { values } = details;

    const valuesData = React.useMemo(() => values ?? [], [
        values
    ]);


    return (
        <ValuesModal
            tableData={valuesData}
        />
    );
}

const ValuesModal: React.FC = ({
    tableData,
}) => {
    const initialValues = React.useMemo(
        () => ({
            values: initialTableData,
        }),
        [initialTableData]
    );

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={async formData => {
                try {
                    await setValues({
                        values:
                            {
                                input: {
                                    values: map(formData.values, 
                                        value => ({
                                            value: 
                                                value.editedValue
                                        })),
                                    }l
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (error)
                        notify({
                            status: 'success'
                        })
                    }}
                >
                    {formikProps => {
                         const {handleSubmit} = formikProps;
                        
                         return (
                             <Modal
                                 actions={
                                     <Button
                                         onClick={() => 
                                             handleSubmit()
                                         }
                                      >Save
                                      </Button>
                                  }
                              />
                          )
                      }
                  }
               />
           );
       }
```

Not sure what is causing the problem. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: This isn't a TypeScript question, even if you're writing it in TypeScript.

Comment: Your code only fetches some data and passes it to another component. The relevant parts are obviously missing. Where is the updating part?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use hook useState, in that way when update de state the page will render updating your data.

Example of use, updating a counting.

```
 function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```